# When is a Mac needed for building Xamarin iOS apps (CI)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, continuous-integration, bamboo

My Bamboo build system (continuous integration) on Windows Server appears to do fine without a mac as it builds the solution with MSBuild. There is no mac connected but I'm considering adding a Mac Mini to my server rack and pairing Visual Studio 2019 to it as well as Bamboo Remote Agent. But is it necessary? When is a Mac needed when it comes to continuous integration and iOS apps? Or Xamarin Forms for that matter?

Comment: There are several CI systems that can build iOS apps. However, they all use some build machines (Macs) to get your build out the door, it just is hidden from the user and part of the service they offer. It is not possible to build an iOS app without a Mac.

Comment: I think you can build with MSBuild but where the macOS comes in is creating IPA files, i.e. beyond the compile but moving to the next step of distribution. If I'm just doing compile testing do I need a paired mac? I'm not sure how my builds compile now when not paired to a mac.

Comment: @Neal  If just doing compile testing you need a paired mac to do that . Have a look at this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/?pivots=windows

Comment: Any compilation of an iOS app relies on XCode one way or another to build the compiled binary and XCode only runs on a Mac.